# How can I change pagination numbers with next and back button?

Tags: pagination

How can I change this pagination:
[image: pagination with numbers]

to look like this:

[image: next and back button]

Please help me, my page code is:

```
if($max_page > 1 || intval($pagenavi_options['always_show']) == 1) {
    $pages_text = str_replace("%CURRENT_PAGE%", number_format_i18n($paged), $pagenavi_options['pages_text']);
    $pages_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pages_text);

    echo '<div class="page-nav td-pb-padding-side">';   
    previous_posts_link($pagenavi_options['prev_text']);
    if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
        $first_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['first_text']);
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link()).'" class="first" title="'.$first_page_text.'">'.$first_page_text.'</a>';
        if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotleft_text']) && ($start_page > 2)) {
            echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'].'</span>';
        }
    }
    /*
    if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_start_page_start > 0 && $larger_start_page_end <= $max_page) {
        for($i = $larger_start_page_start; $i < $larger_start_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
            $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
        }
        echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'].'</span>';
    }*/

    for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {
        if($i == $paged) {
            $current_page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['current_text']);
            echo '<span class="current">'.$current_page_text.'</span>';
        } else {
            $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
        }
    }

    /*
    if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_end_page_start < $max_page) {
        echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'].'</span>';
       for($i = $larger_end_page_start; $i <= $larger_end_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
           $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
           echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
       }
    }*/
    if ($end_page < $max_page) {
        if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotright_text']) && ($end_page + 1 < $max_page)) {
            echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'].'</span>';
        }

        $last_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['last_text']);
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max_page)).'" class="last" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$last_page_text.'</a>';
    }
    next_posts_link($pagenavi_options['next_text'], $max_page);
    if(!empty($pages_text)) {
        echo '<span class="pages">'.$pages_text.'</span>';
    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
the_posts_pagination(array(
        prev_text => 'PREV',
        next_text => 'NEXT',
        screen_reader_text => ' ' 
        ));
```

For pagination You should try this. Hope this will help you.

Comment: where can i find this code